# Faking a generic method call in C# is not returning the correct object with FakeItEasy

Tags: c#, unit-testing, fakeiteasy

I have this method I need to test

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> Completed(string nprUserId, [FromBody] DateRangeDto model)
    {
        var result = await _geAppService.Completed<ExpandoObject>(nprUserId, model.StartDate, model.EndDate);
        var r = result as OperationResult;

        if (r == null)
        {
            // There is no error.  Return JSON
            return Json(result, camelCaseOption);
        }
        else
        {
            // An error occurred.  Return a 404 and include the error message
            return NotFound(r.ErrorMessage);
        }
    }
```

This is my test

```
    [Fact]
    [Trait("Controller", "Completed")]
    public async Task Completed_WhenRIsNotNull_ReturnNotFoundWithMessage()
    {
        //arrange
        string nprUserId = string.Empty;
        var model = CreateRandomDateRangeDto();
        OperationResult r = CreateRandomOperationResult();
        var startDate = DateTime.Now;
        var endDate = DateTime.Now;

        //I tried this
        A.CallTo(nprAppService)
            .Where(call => call.Method.Name == "Completed")
            .WithReturnType<OperationResult>()
            .Returns(r);
       //I tried this as well
        A.CallTo(() => nprAppService.Completed<ExpandoObject>(nprUserId, startDate, endDate))
            .Returns(r);

        //act
        var result = await controller.Completed(nprUserId, model);

        // Assert
        A.CallTo(() => nprAppService.Completed<ExpandoObject>(nprUserId, startDate, endDate))
            .MustHaveHappened();
        result.Should().BeOfType<NotFoundObjectResult>()
            .Subject.Value.Should().BeOfType<string>();
    }
```

When the **sut**: controller gets called, the Complete generic method returns an object instead of an OperationResult.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Why your approaches didn't work:
First approach: we don't see the definition of `nprAppService.Completed`, but based on the `r = result as OperationResult`, I'm guessing it doesn't return an `OperationResult`. So `WithReturnType<OperationResult>` causes your call configuration not to match. I expect if you switched that to `WithNonVoidReturnType`, you'd have success.
Second approach: just as @Chekkan said, you configure the fake to respond to specific date arguments only, so when other ones were supplied, FakeItEasy applied its default behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `CreateRandomDateRangeDto` returns the model with `StartDate` and `EndDate` set to `DateTime.Now`,

Your test should be using `model.StartDate` and `model.EndDate` instead of `startDate`, and `endDate` in the test method. because their values will be different.

```
 [Fact]
 [Trait("Controller", "Completed")]
 public async Task Completed_WhenRIsNotNull_ReturnNotFoundWithMessage()
 {
     //arrange
     string nprUserId = string.Empty;
     var model = CreateRandomDateRangeDto();
     OperationResult r = CreateRandomOperationResult();

     A.CallTo(() => nprAppService.Completed<ExpandoObject>(nprUserId, model.StartDate, model.EndDate))
        .Returns(r);

    //act
    var result = await controller.Completed(nprUserId, model);

    // Assert
    A.CallTo(() => nprAppService.Completed<ExpandoObject>(nprUserId, model.StartDate, model.EndDate))
        .MustHaveHappened();
    result.Should().BeOfType<NotFoundObjectResult>()
        .Subject.Value.Should().BeOfType<string>();
}
```

**Update**: Further explanation

For the first approach of configuring through passing the fake object, the return type should include `Task`.

```cs
A.CallTo(nprAppService)
    .Where(call => call.Method.Name == "Completed")
    .WithReturnType<Task<OperationResult>>()
    .Returns(r)
```

The second approach requires the exact value/object in order to return the specified object. That's why the test only works with `model.EndDate` and `model.StartDate`

If you didn't care about the start and end date values matching, you can...

```cs
A.CallTo(() => nprAppService.Completed<ExpandoObject>(nprUserId, A<DateTime>._, A<DateTime>._))
                .Returns(r);
```

Comment: why the values passed are important in this case?

Comment: added more explanation with an Update, hopefully, makes things clearer.